# forEach works fine in onClick but not without

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to append an `<li>` attribute to the list of servers, it isn't executing the `forEach()` - I tried `console.log()` nested but it ignores it like the `Servers` is an empty array?

```js
$(function() {

  var Discord = {
    Servers: [{
      Name: 'Server 1',
      Link: 'hidden for security'
    }, {
      Name: 'Server 2',
      Link: 'hidden for security'
    }]
  };

  $('#_discord_notify_btn').click(function() {
    Discord.Servers.forEach(function($server) {
      $.post($server.Link, {
        content: $('#_discord_notify').val()
      });
    });
  });
  
  // this code is ignored??
  Discord.Servers.forEach(function($server) {
    $('_discord_servers ul').append("<li>" + $server.Name + "</li>");
  });

});
```

```css
textarea {
  min-width: 447px;
  min-height: 110px;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='_discord_servers'>
  <b>Servers you're notifying</b>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<textarea id='_discord_notify'>Enter your notification...</textarea>
<button type='button' id='_discord_notify_btn'>
  Send Notification
</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the # for the ID selector in your second example.

```
// this code is ignored??
  Discord.Servers.forEach(function($server) {
    $('#_discord_servers ul').append("<li>" + $server.Name + "</li>");
  });
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, appreciated! I'll mark when I can!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the id selector:

```js
$(function() {

  var Discord = {
    Servers: [{
      Name: 'Server 1',
      Link: 'hidden for security'
    }, {
      Name: 'Server 2',
      Link: 'hidden for security'
    }]
  };

  $('#_discord_notify_btn').click(function() {
    Discord.Servers.forEach(function($server) {
      $.post($server.Link, {
        content: $('#_discord_notify').val()
      });
    });
  });
  
  // this code is ignored??
  Discord.Servers.forEach(function($server) {
    console.log('test');
    $('#_discord_servers ul').append("<li>" + $server.Name + "</li>");
  });

});
```

```css
textarea {
  min-width: 447px;
  min-height: 110px;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='_discord_servers'>
  <b>Servers you're notifying</b>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<textarea id='_discord_notify'>Enter your notification...</textarea>
<button type='button' id='_discord_notify_btn'>
  Send Notification
</button>
```